# NOT to soft delete a row in a table that contain foreign key to other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am doing soft delete in all my tables. I should not soft delete a row when that ID is referred in other tables. Also, when the referred child table is deleted i.e, Isdeleted = 1, then I should be able to soft delete the parent record.

Your suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: How can a child *table* have an `IsDeleted` flag?

Comment: IsDeleted flag is in parent table. I want to soft delete the parent table record. If the record is referenced in any of the child table then I should not do the soft delete.

Comment: What about `UPDATE Parent SET IsDeleted = 1 FROM Parent p WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Child WHERE ParentID = p.ID)`?

Comment: Thanks for your update. Here I have many child tables. For example I have Department table in which DepartmentID is referred in many tables and can also be referred to future development. When I try to delete a department and if that department is referred to any other table then I should not be able to do the soft delete.

Comment: For that, and assuming you have foreign key relationships defined, you need to use the system tables and some dynamic sql but I don't have an hour to spare trying to figure that out.

Comment: Why you want this dynamic? Your database design is fixed at any time, even if you change it you can modify your rules. So I suggest you make a stored procedure to soft delete your main table and inside you just count on all your relating tables. Set right indexes and this will be fast. I don't see a reason to do this totally dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to generate some dynamic sql from the schema. I don't have time to pivot all the items into dynamic sql here, but you could use either a cursor loop or possibly `PIVOT` for the dynamic SQL:

```
-- parent/child schemas, tables, columns
select parent_schema=p.TABLE_SCHEMA
, parent_table=p.TABLE_NAME
, parent_pk_column=p.COLUMN_NAME
, child_schema=c.TABLE_SCHEMA
, child_table=c.TABLE_NAME
, child_fk_column=c.COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE p
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS pc
    on pc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA=p.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
    and pc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME=p.CONSTRAINT_NAME
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE c
    on c.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA=pc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
    and c.CONSTRAINT_NAME=pc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
where exists(
    select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where COLUMN_NAME='IsDeleted' and TABLE_SCHEMA=p.TABLE_SCHEMA and TABLE_NAME=p.TABLE_NAME
)

-- tables/pk columns having IsDeleted column but no children
select parent_schema=p.TABLE_SCHEMA
, parent_table=p.TABLE_NAME
, parent_column=p.COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE p
where not exists(
    select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS 
    where UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA=p.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
    and UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME=p.CONSTRAINT_NAME
)
and exists(
    select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where COLUMN_NAME='IsDeleted' and TABLE_SCHEMA=p.TABLE_SCHEMA and TABLE_NAME=p.TABLE_NAME
)
```